# Is there any way to access SAP SMTP directly through nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, hana

I created a nodejs app in SAP HANA with business application studio (CAP project). I used `sap-hana-client` library to access SAP HANA database tables and fetch some data. After that I manipulate the data and use them to create email (data are transformed to CSV attachments) with nodemailer. Until now everything works correctly with gmail SMTP. But I need to send emails through SAP SMTP.

Is there any way to configure nodemailer with SAP SMTP credentials and send the email via SAP instead of Google?

I checked and found that there is Alert Notification Service in SAP but still I would prefer to just connect via nodejs app directly to SAP SMTP and send the emails to the recipients predefined in nodemailer mail options.

Comment: what do you mean by SAP SMTP? SAP ECC has no built-in SMTP-server, SCOT/SOST provides only configuration-wrapping of the SMTP-provider that client must already have

Comment: In Sap Hana there is email notification service . In this case Sap Smtp is used for emails to be sent. The question is can I access the same Sap SMTP directly from node Js code? ( In a similar way google Smtp is configured in nodemailer) .

Comment: you mean HANA DB [alert notification service](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.05/en-US/1581c9b2591e41ebae6615567c2dac2c.html) or S4HANA? There is no such entity as "SAP SMTP", any standard alerting function in S4HANA or ECC will use SCOT parameters. And no, there is no way to get its credential to outside

Comment: Alert notification service. I have a use case in which I need to send email push notifications every 1 hour with specific data from db. I thought that it would be possible to use the Smtp, through nodejs, that sap uses internally to send these email push notifications . But you say that this is impossible. So is there the alternative to trigger the alert notification service from nodejs? Is there also the option to fully manipulate  body,attachments & recipients with data from sap hana db ? If yes it would be very helpful to share any tutorials you may have on the subject.thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Pro in nodejs and dunno if it has a built-in smtp-server, but SAP definitely does not.

Comment: No worries . Thanks for your support.